# Rendering Text in LWJGL

Tags: text, rendering, lwjgl

What is the simplest way to render text in LWJGL without any extra jars?
I searched around and saw so many complicated solutions, I wondered what is the simplest way?

Comment: There is no "simple" way of rendering text in the LWJGL. Try placing all the characters in a sprite sheet and then loading in that sprite sheet.

Comment: Perfect Idea! Once I get the sprite sheets working ill use this idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sprite sheets! It's nice and simple and you can generate a sprite sheet for text using **Bitmap Font Generators**!